Bipolar stepper motor - can't decide whether its defective or not
I am trying to control a two phase bipolar stepper motor using a TMCM-3212 module. The parameters of the stepper motors are 0.96 A rated current and 2.66 V.
When I first ran the Python script of the module, it rotated for a long time (even though it was supposed to rotate for only small movements) and then suddenly stopped. Unknowingly, I used the driver current as 128 (1.28 A), which is above the rated current of the motor.
Since then, the motor has never rotated (even though I changed the driver current to 79). I have double-checked the connections of both the motor and module. Even there is current and voltage flow across the module and motor, but the motor shaft is not rotating. There is also voltage across the coil terminals. Moreover, when providing a small current to the coil terminals using a battery, the motor shafts rotate in both clockwise and anticlockwise directions (step-wise).
This is the reason why I can't decide whether the motor is defective or not.
Can anyone help me to determine if it's the motor or the driver which is defective?
